# Connecting python script to HTML for rock, paper, scissors game for basic project

Tags: python, html

Trying my hand at coding in Python3 and HTML trying to teach my self with YouTube tutorials, this site, and the occasional help for ChatGPT. So I have built an initial script with 1 Python script and 2 HTML codes (one for the front page and a second one for show the result of the game). It's a touch clumsy, but it's a first attempt and I am trying to get the hang of all of this.

The two files work fine on their own, but the problem begins to arise when I try and play and instead of the next page containing what the player choose, the computer-generated number, and a result of having won, lost, or tied, I get the raw HTML code which looks something like this.

```
<body>
<h1 class="custom-heading">Result</h1>
<p>You chose:</p>
<p>The computer chose: {{ computer_choice }}</p>
<p>{{ result }}</p>
```

Or, sometimes it produces a 404 error. I am just trying to run the HTML application for my own personal use on my macOS computer. I am using PyCharm IDE to build and run the software.

After much labour, I built this program to connect the python script to the HTML files.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import random

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        player_choice = request.form['choice']
        return redirect(url_for('play', player_choice=player_choice))
    return render_template('Rock_Paper_Scissors.html')

@app.route('/play/<player_choice>', methods=['GET'])
def play(player_choice):
    computer_choice = generate_computer_choice()
    result = determine_result(player_choice, computer_choice)
    return redirect(url_for('result', player_choice=player_choice, computer_choice=computer_choice, result=result))

@app.route('/result/<player_choice>/<computer_choice>/<result>', methods=['GET'])
def result(player_choice, computer_choice, result):
    return render_template('Result.html', player_choice=player_choice, computer_choice=computer_choice, result=result)
```

In the body section of the HTML text, I tried this in order to feed through the home function that I had built in the python script.

```
<form class="class1" action="{{ url_for('play') }}" method="post">
    <label for="choice">Choose:</label>
    <select name="choice" id="choice">
        <option value="rock">Rock</option>
        <option value="paper">Paper</option>
        <option value="scissors">Scissors</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Play">
</form>
```

This would then be fed back into the Flask code that I have create and produce the result from the game functions and the results which would be spat out through a separate html file (titled 'Result.html') which looks like this.

```
<body>
<h1 class="custom-heading">Result</h1>
<p>You chose:</p>
<p>The computer chose: {{ computer_choice }}</p>
<p>{{ result }}</p>
```

Is there anyway to get this to work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are all the templates in the `templates` folder?

Comment: Where do you start the app w/ `app.run(host, port)`?

Comment: This isn't likely to fix the problem, but shouldn't your player choice line be: `<p>You chose: {{ player_choice }}</p>`

Comment: You're also missing a `determine_result` function.

Comment: Yes, I recommend reading some books from your local library, if you want to learn to code.